# How would you recommend securing a pannier rack on a bike without braze-ons?

Tags: rack

My bike has lugs for mudguards/rack down by the rear drop-outs, but not in the usual places at the top of the seat-stays.

My two options seem to be:

- use P-clips around the seat-stays
- fashion a single bracket extending from the centre of the rack to the bolt-hole on the rear brake bridge

The first option seems easier and less fussy, but perhaps there's another way.

Comment: Sunlite racks actually come with a bracket that fits to the brake bolt. I personally prefer p clamps because they allow a higher position, but they can run the paint off even if they are rubber coated

Comment: @Andrew: Wrap rubber or duct tape around the seat stays before you tighten the clamps.

Comment: The bracket I made has broken. https://www.topeak.com/global/en/products/99-Replacement-Kit/815-CENTER-BOLT-CLIP looks like a stronger way of uniting the rack with the frame; are there other parts available that do the same job?

Answer (score 6):

The two options you mention are widely used.

Another option is a [seatpost clamp with rack mount points](https://www.jonesbikes.com/problem-solvers-seatpost-clamp-with-rack-mounts/)
There are a variety of makers and styles, here is one example.
[image]

Comment: I have an old steel frame in which the clamp is part of the seat-tube, so the clamp you suggest sadly won't work (otherwise it would have been ideal).

Comment: @DanieleProcida, in that case just make/purchase some shims and clamp around the post only. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DanieleProcida What is the downside with P clamps? I don't like them because they are ugly and clunky but I'd use them if I had to. Is clamping to the seatpost an option? There are versions of this clamp for seatposts. Old steel frames are wonderful

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the rack to the brake bridge, yes, any decent bike shop should be able to do that when installing the rack.

Or you buy a rack that clamps to the seat post: the Pletscher quick rack system will attach directly to the seat tube, so no need for the eyelets. https://www.pletscher.ch/index.php/en/products-en/carriers-en/quickrack-carriers-en They carry up to 25 kgs, as other racks.

Or you can go fancy 
https://www.tailfin.cc/

Comment: A rack which attaches to the brake bridge will be much lighter. For example the Tubus Fly weighs 420g while the Pletscher Athlete is 940g.

Comment: @Michael I guess the Pletscher is a bit over-engineered, because it provides the quick removal possibility, with no tools it can be removed simply by releasing the QR and rotting backward and sliding out.

Comment: +1, single strut to brake bridge is the right answer.